# How to avoid creating a new instance of MediaPlayer when returning to activity

Tags: java, android, view, connection, media-player

I'm using the MediaPlayer and it keeps playing in the background when the user leaves the activity by pressing back (I want this to happen), however when the user returns, they have no control over the already playing MediaPlayer since the line `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()` instantiates a new one.

I also cannot get `mediaPlayer.create()` to work since I am using a connection to soundcloud requiring the

```
mediaPlayer1.reset();
mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(getResources().getString(R.string.Basic_lesson_1));
mediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
```

lines. How can I instantiate a new MediaPlayer only if one does not already exist?

Comment: create static media player and check if not null

Comment: @Pravin this fixed it, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Create Global static media Player and always perform validation as @Pravin says
while create media player like.

```
if(mediaPlayer == null){
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer()
 }
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = null;

//SomeActivity's onCreate()
if(mediaPlayer1 == null)
    mediaPlayer1.create(...);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about evoking the method stop() on backKeyPress

Comment: I need the MediaPlayer to keep playing though :P